# [TemplateContainer(typeof(MasterPage.Site1))]

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, master-pages

I have this error. How can I solve it?

> CS0426: The type name 'Site1' does not exist in the type 'MasterPage'

Here is my masterpage code:

[image]

Comment: The `Inherits` property looks wrong. Should be `yourNameSpace.Site1`.

Answer (score 2):

The other answer will most likely be the cause.  However, I have also run into this error if you name your project a reserved name.

For example, if you name your project "Login" or "UpdatePanel" you will also get this error.

The fix is to name your project something else.  For example "CompanyLogin" or "CompanyPanel".

Answer (score 1):

You need to set your *inherits*  attribute on markup of master page with  your fully qualified class name . Saying that open "*Site1.master.cs*" and you will see your class name which inherits from *MasterPage* .if class is part of a namespace then you should set youtr inherits attribute with [Namespace].[ClassName]

For example in my sample project. My master page has following directive on top

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Site.master.cs" Inherits="SiteMaster" %>
```

And My Codebehind class (Site.master.cs) is : see *SiteMaster* is the class my master page inherits from. Asp.Net Form engine compiles markup into a class which derives from a base class i behind the scenes

```
public partial class SiteMaster : MasterPage
{
    private const string AntiXsrfTokenKey = "__AntiXsrfToken";
    private const string AntiXsrfUserNameKey = "__AntiXsrfUserName";
    private string _antiXsrfTokenValue;

    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)

}
```